# GoogleVis or GGVis, build graphs with different database structure

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis, googlevis

I'm a statistician in pharmaceutical industry. In my free-time I'm trying to learn some Shiny R programming and I would like to build something on some clinical research data (the main reason is that I understand the domain and I have a lot of data).

We usually work on SAS datasets and I managed to import them in R as dataframe.

I'm in front of a limit and really don't know how to get rid of it, the dataset structure.

The usual dataset structure I have is this one:

```
PT   VISIT    VAR1
001  Visit 1  100
001  Visit 2  120
002  Visit 1  110
002  Visit 2  90
```

I managed to setup the code to run my first linechart but I noticed that both GGVIS and GOOGLEVIS are meant to work on a database of this kind

```
VISIT    PT001  PT002
Visit 1  100    110
Visit 2  120    90
```

And this is more than a problem to me, because I don't want to transpose all the datasets and also I don't want to create one variable for each patients because they are usually dinamic (the number of patients usually changes over time).

Do you know if there is a way to handle my usual dataset structure, grouping on the value of the Patient variable?

I would include my code but it is pretty basic and totally useless in this case, but if you want, just ask and I will include it.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `dcast` from package `data.table`

Comment: thank you @HubertL, really appreciate your comment. this is what I meant for transposing the dataset. Anyway I would really prefer to not transpose the dataset and keep the original structure of the data that, something, could be far more complex than this. Do you know if there is a way to work with ggvis or googlevis, without working to much on the dataset? thank you again.

Comment: I don't call one `dcast` instruction __working to much__. Maybe you want to post your code so that it makes sense?

Comment: Dear @HubertL, I know that it would be easy to do it, but I have reasons in my willing to preserve the structure of the data. As I already wrote, the patients number should be dinamic.

Comment: @stat I don't understand your question. `ggvis` expects data to be in "_The usual dataset structure [you] have_", a long format. Can you please provide a concrete example where you fail to use such a data format in `ggvis`, or relevant parts of docs? I have voted to close your question as unclear.